# Need to find a compatible ac adapter

Tags: electrical

I have a Syemour Duncan guitar effects pedal that I bought several years back. I seem to have lost the power adapter for it and they don't make them anymore. I looked at the power input on the pedal and it says `16V~ / 560mA`. The manual says

> Do not try to substitute a DC power supply or another AC supply with a
>   different voltage or current rating.

They give a [website](https://www.digikey.com) where you can buy a replacement adapter, but the only [applicable replacement](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=MT7123-ND) I could find is no longer carried.

However, I did find [this adapter on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B8865BG). The voltage matches but the current is 1000 mA. It's my (fairly uninformed) understanding that it's okay for the adapter's current to be higher than the device's. At least that supposedly true for DC current. Not sure about AC. Would the amazon adapter be safe to use?

I also notice that the amazon adapter lists the plug as being 2.1mm. I'm not sure if that's compatible with my pedal. Is there anyway to know?

Comment: This is probably better on EE.SE considering it's in the device-side of the world (vs. the house-wiring side)...

Comment: Yeah I almost put it there but everything seemed a bit too advanced for this question. I'll try there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **It's my (fairly uninformed) understanding that it's okay for the adapter's current to be higher than the device's.**

That is true. The adapter rating is the *maximum* current it is can supply. It will work quite happily with lower current loads.

> **Would the amazon adapter be safe to use?**

Yes, if the voltage matches what the pedal requires - 16V AC.

I assume it is well-made and meets all local regulations. Not everything sold on Amazon is.

---

> **the plug as being 2.1mm. I'm not sure if that's compatible**

That is a very common standard. Unfortunately the problem with standards is that there are so many to choose from.

It is actually not hard to change the connector with a wire-cutter and soldering iron. You can buy or make adapters quite easily. Parts are available from lots of places (eBay, Amazon, electrical distribution businesses, hobby-electronics online stores, ...) For a 16V AC supply, there should not be any safety concern in making these sort of changes at the low-voltage end.